# Tips for using SQL skills efficiently in Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

As a Marketing Cloud marketeer I really see queries as very powerful in creating strong segments.
So, I've dived into SQL and query writing using codeacademy and w3schools, but even though I find these resources valuable, I have a very hard time using my new SQL skills in Automation Studio as I find the entire setup both slow, as results needs to be populated into a data extension, and hard to debug, as error descriptions seem inadequate.
This might be related to me being a new kids using queries and new to SQL, but I doubt I'm the only one going through this phase.

So, everyone mastering queries in Automation Studio in Marketing Cloud, what have you done to ease the transition of SQL skills outside of Marketing Cloud to be useful in Marketing Cloud in order to work as efficiently as possible?

Any tips might help, as I really feel this being a personal obstacle I need to overcome, to be a better marketeer :)

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would look into using Query Studio which is much more user-friendly and better for trial and error development work. [Query Studio](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FP3yFUAT). It will help you as you learn and get up to speed.

I'd also really recommend reviewing the query/SQL documentation that SFMC has provided because it will help understand the limitations of SQL in SFMC vs the outside world.  [SFMC SQL Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5)

As with anything it will take time, but you'll get better and learn the nuances to SFMC when it comes to writing queries.